# Does there exists a sequence $T_n$ such that $\|T_n-T\|\rightarrow 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

> Let $(a_n)_n\in \ell^\infty$ and define $$T:\ell^2\rightarrow \ell^2: (x_n)\mapsto (a_nx_n)$$ Assume that $a_n\rightarrow 0$. I want to check if there exists a sequence $T_n$ such that $T_n\rightarrow T$

My guess would be $T_n((x_n)_n)=(a_1x_1,...,a_nx_n,0,0,.....)$ then $$\begin{align}\|T_n-T\|^2&=\sup_{\|x\|_2\leq 1}\sum_{k>n} |a_kx_k|^2\\&\leq \sup_{\|x\|_2\leq 1}\|x\|_2^2\sup_{k>n}|a_k| \\&\leq \sup_{k>n}|a_k|\rightarrow 0 \end{align}$$

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct but your question is "wrong" ;-) Of course you do not just want a sequence $T_n\to T,$ otherwise you'd just have to take $T_n=T.$

Comment: @AnneBauval no I think also my answer is wrong since $T_n-T$ is not the sum I wrote above

Comment: Oh sorry I did not read carefully. You are right (to say it is wrong): change all $k\le n$'s to $k>n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval yes you are right I got it also in this moment

Comment: @AnneBauval now I think it works

Comment: Yes, and note you've thus proved that $T$ is a [compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space).

Comment: @AnneBauval really? I thought for compactness we also need $\dim(T_n(\ell^2))<\infty$

Comment: Yes, here $ \dim(T_n(\ell^2))=n.$ Btw, I found a kind of duplicate: [Is the multiplication operator on $\ell^p$ compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013736/is-the-multiplication-operator-on-ellp-compact)

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry it does not, is the dimension here finite?

Comment: @AnneBauval how do I get this? I don't see how that one can compute the dimension of an operator?

Comment: It is not the "dimension of an operator" but of its range. The range of $T_n$ is a subspace of sequences $(x_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ s.t. $x_k=0$ for all $k>n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval but in this subspace couldn't I have infinitely many sequences with this property?

Comment: Of course, the finite-*dimensional* space $\Bbb R^m$ is an infinite *set* (for $m>0$)

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry I am still a bit confused so how can we immediately see that the dimension of its range is $n$?

Comment: In fact it might be smaller if some of the numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are $0.$ But assume for simplicity it is not the case. Then the range is exactly $\Bbb R^n\times\{(0,0,\dots)\},$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n.$ If you only want to prove it is finite dimensional, you only need to see it is a subspace of that space.

Comment: @AnneBauval ah okey I see perfect thanks!